# Local GIT server authentication

Tags: git, authentication, url, local

I just setup a VM (Ubuntu Server 20.04.2), I setup GIT server on it which is working.

When I run `git clone git@VM-IP:repos/repo` it is cloning `repo` from `repos` dir in `git`'s account `home dir` (or basically `/home/git/repos/repo`).

After I run the clone it is asking for password. If I use the `git`'s account password it clones successfully. If I use `passwordA` (also tried with `user@VM-IP..` as well) it is failing. I created `.ssh/authorized_keys` in `/home/git` in which I put the result of execution of `ssh-keygen -t rsa` from `user` in which I enter `passwordA`.

After browsing this issue for a while I've found a couple of url formats:

```
1) git@VM-IP:repo-path
2) git@VM-IP:user/repo-path
3) user@VM-IP:repo-path
```

Which of those is correct if I want to use `user`'s password to clone the repo from `/home/git/repo`?
Also am I missing something with the keys or is it just URL issue?

Comment: which is the version control tool you are using?

Comment: Normally, the `git` user is used for all git operations using ssh authentication. Different users just have different ssh keys uploaded to it so they can access it (other access with those ssh keys is normally restricted)

Comment: @Kiran I'm trying to make it run from the terminal at first and then will switch to Sublime Merge probably (Sublime Merge is working with the git account as well as the terminal).


@dan1st Does that mean that `git` shall not have a password, but rather have multiple ssh keys for login? I've read that as well while browsing and I'm not really sure how to utilize it.
Also can I assume that `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` path is correct or should it be somewhere else?

Thanks for the replies! : ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that were holding me back.

1. `git` had password. If that is your case run `sudo passwd -d git` from your main user.
2. There was one invalid key in the file so it was not reading it. For successful authentication you need `user` to generate rsa pair with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and it should be in `/home/user/.ssh`, keep it there. Copy the content from `id_rsa.pub` into `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` (Note that one line = one record!). Now if you do `sudo su user; git clone git@localhost:repos/repo` it will ask you for password of `user` and will clone `/home/git/repos/repo` into `/home/user/repo`.

With those two things everything is working now. Thanks for the replies!